# Displaying Simple Product Stock On Configurable Product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, product-view, simple-product

Im currently using **Magento CE 1.9** and I want to display the individual stock quantities of all the simple products associated with the configurable product.

When you click the "Only X Left" message on the product page on the front end these products display as per `/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/composite.phtml`

However only the quantities are showing but the simple product titles are note displaying.

Can anyone suggest why the titles aren't displaying and how to fix this?

Also how can you get this table to display showing all the quantities to display without having to click on the message?

Comment: please mention magento version

Comment: It says Magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template

```
/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/composite.phtml
```

the table on line 35 got css-class "no-display":

```
<table id="<?php echo $this->getDetailsPlaceholderId() ?>" class="availability-only-details no-display">
```

override the template in your design and delete the "no-display" css-class...
and then format the table to fit your needs.
If you do, you can also remove the javscript at the bottom of the template-file from line 56 to 65

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('<?php echo $this->getPlaceholderId() ?>').observe('click', function(event){
    this.toggleClassName('expanded');
    $('<?php echo $this->getDetailsPlaceholderId() ?>').toggleClassName('no-display');
    event.stop();
    decorateTable('<?php echo $this->getDetailsPlaceholderId() ?>');
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that the table is now displaying as expected - do you have any ideas/suggestions on why the simple product names are not displaying in the table but the quantities are?

Comment: The table has the following:

       <?php foreach ($this->getChildProducts() as $childProduct) : ?>
            <?php $childProductStockQty = $this->getProductStockQty($childProduct); ?>
            <?php if ($childProductStockQty > 0) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $childProduct->getName() ?></td>
                    <td class="a-center"><?php echo $childProductStockQty ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>

Comment: maybe the attribute for the name of the product is not "name"?=

Comment: and please dont forget to mark my answer as useful.